# Write Line error in C#

Tags: c#, error-handling, console, syntax-error, console-application

I have an assignment to create a record-keeping console application in C# for adding, viewing, and deleting records. I need to use an array, list, or dictionary (or some combination).

I have tried using arrays and lists, but so far dictionaries have proved the most successful (aka I know how to use them best in this program). In the photo is the code I have so far, but I am getting errors when I prompt the user to enter information. I have tried a few different fixes but none have worked.

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmVIx.png)

```
    class Patient
    {
        public static string PatientDict;
            public Console.WriteLine("Enter the patient's name: "); 
        string PatientName = Console.ReadLine();
            public Console.WriteLine("Enter the patient's date of birth: "); 
        string PatientDOB = Console.ReadLine();
            public Console.WriteLine("Enter the patient's age: "); 
        string PatientAge = Console.ReadLine();
            public Console.WriteLine("Enter the patient's ailment(s): "); 
        string PatientAilments = Console.ReadLine();
            public Console.WriteLine("Enter the patient's medication(s): "); 
        string PatientMeds = Console.ReadLine();

        string DOB;
        string Age;
        string Ailments;
        string Meds;
    }
```

Comment: `public Console.WriteLine("Enter the patient's name: ");`? I think you need to keep reading a c# tutorial, that's not valid at all

Comment: Create a method to place the code into, you're confusing fields with statements.

Comment: From what I remember from class, Console.WriteLine(); was what my prof used and what I have found online ? (I added public as a random fix attempt)

Comment: Your prof probably did use `Console.WriteLine()`; only correctly. Do not attempt to fix code by making random changes; programming is too complicated to learn that way. Instead; [read tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/quick-starts/) and the [documentation(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list of your objects (patients) like so:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a new list of patients to store your values
        List<Patient> patients = new List<Patient>();

        // Get user input and store them as variables
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the patients name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the patients date of birth: ");
        string dob = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the patients age: ");
        int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the patients ailment(s): ");
        string ailments = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the patients medication(s): ");
        string meds = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine(); // Empty line


        // Add the given input to the list of patients
        patients.Add(new Patient { patientName = name, patientDOB = dob, patientAilments = ailments, patientMeds = meds, patientAGE = age });


        // Print patients to console output
        foreach (var patient in patients)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Patients name = {0}", patient.patientName);
            Console.WriteLine("Patients date of birth = {0}", patient.patientDOB);
            Console.WriteLine("Patients age = {0}", patient.patientAGE);
            Console.WriteLine("Patients ailment(s) = {0}", patient.patientAilments);
            Console.WriteLine("Patients medication(s) = {0}", patient.patientMeds);
        }
    }
}

class Patient
{
    public string patientName { get; set; }
    public string patientDOB { get; set; }
    public string patientAilments { get; set; }
    public string patientMeds { get; set; }
    public int patientAGE { get; set; }
}
```

This is just one of the many ways to do what you want. If you want to enter more patients simply prompt a new set of questions and add them to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to rewrite your program. You have multiple cases of `Main` methods and `Console.WriteLine(...)` is not method-level code.

It looks like you want to do all of this in the main method, so consider just:

```
class Patient 
{
    static void main(string[] args) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the patient's name: "); 
        string PatientName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the patient's date of birth: "); 
        string PatientDOB = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the patient's age: "); 
        string PatientAge = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the patient's ailment(s): "); 
        string PatientAilments = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the patient's medication(s): "); 
        string PatientMeds = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

As a starting point, and read more about [C# & tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/quick-starts/)

Comment: There should be 2 classes: The Program class containing the Main method doing the user interaction and a Patient class with properties only.